# Excel Formula to sum amount found in one list by lookup value found in another list

Tags: excel, sum, formula, lookup

Looking for an Excel formula to sum amounts by a lookup category found in another list.  Think 3 lists in total. Here is the setup.

List1 is **Category**: Fruit, Vegetable and **Amount**.  The formula goes under Amount.
List2 is **Item**: Apple, Carrot, Banana, Lettuce  and **Amount**: 4,3,5,2.
List3 is the crosswalk... **Item**: Apple, Carrot, Banana, Lettuce  and  **Category**: Fruit, Vegetable, Fruit, Vegetable.

Without changing either list2 or list3 is there a formula get the total amount for list2 and the category from list3 to populate Amount in list1?

3 Lists Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If one has Office 365:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,FILTER($G$2:$G$5,$H$2:$H$5=A2)))
```

[image]

---

If not then we need to use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$E$7)*(A2=INDEX(H:H,MATCH($D$2:$D$7,G:G,0))))
```

[image]